# Featured image in admin on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I followed [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen/) to getting featured images to show in the admin menu on posts. I wanted to be able to see what article had a featured image and what it looked like without having to actually edit the article.

The article worked, but I noticed that it didn't work on my custom post type. So I went looking for the filter that would make it work and found [manage_edit-post_type_columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns)

I have a custom post type for "Events". The slug for this is "events". I figured from the codex that if I did this

```
add_filter('manage_events_custom_columns', 'ST4_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

It would work but it has not. I can see the column for the featured image in the admin menu but I do not see the image in the column next to the post.

Comment: Can you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both codes and they worked for me,

first I added this code

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'bootpress_slider_columns');  
function bootpress_slider_columns($defaults) {  
    $defaults['featured_image'] = 'Featured Image';  
    return $defaults;  
}
```

and it added column both in custom post type and on posts

Then I followed this link [manage_${post_type}_posts_columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns)

my post type is "slider"

the below code worked for me

```
add_filter('manage_slider_posts_columns', 'bootpress_slider_columns');  
function bootpress_slider_columns($defaults) {  
    $defaults['featured_image'] = 'Featured Image';  
    return $defaults;  
}
```

in your case the below code should work

```
add_filter('manage_events_posts_columns', 'ST4_columns_content', 10, 2);
```